# ffmpeg - showinfo in combination with vcodec copy

Tags: ffmpeg, mjpeg

I am trying to extract the frames from an mjpeg video and simoultanously getting timestamps for the individuall frames with ffmpeg.

I can do it with

```
ffmpeg.exe" -i mjpegvideo.avi -filter:v "showinfo" frame%d.jpg
```

but this is pretty slow compared to

```
ffmpeg.exe" -i mjpegvideo.avi -vcodec copy frame%d.jpg
```

because in the first command, a conversion is done. However, if i try to use `-filter:v "showinfo` with `-vcodec copy`, I get an error: `Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

Is there any way to get the frame-timestamps while using `vcodec copy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply copy the encoding of the input the timestamps should remain untouched so you can just do:

`ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames mjpegvideo.avi`

The command can also output JSON or XML, see the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html). This can take a while for large files but at least it won't transcode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Requieres two commands instead of one, but is much much faster (6s vs. 25s for 400 frames).
Ans thanks as well for the tipp on json. Else I would have piped the cmd output to python and parsed it there, but this is much more comfortable.